# How to return variables to a widget from a modal in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget with a list box, clicking on an item opens a window for editing. In it, I can change 2 fields, both of type DateTime.

I do not understand how I can return these variables from the modal window to the main widget, I will be glad for any help

In modal i have two TextEdit controller for redact:

```
TextEditingController _comeInController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _goOutController = TextEditingController();
```

I wan return this variables to main widget and send to server

And my modal:

```
showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
       expand: false,
       context: context,
       builder: (context, scrollController) =>
                           Container(
                                    height: 400,
                                    child: RedactTimesheeft(
                                      comeIN: DateTime.parse(
                                          staffTimeList.parseComeIn),
                                      goOut: staffTimeList.parseGoOut != null
                                          ? DateTime.parse(
                                              staffTimeList.parseGoOut)
                                          : null,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
```

Comment: Why not use your TextEditingController in your main widget? Then use them in the ModalBottomSheet and when you close the ModalBottomSheet you can still access them in your main window

Comment: Hi @Lulupointu! 
I thought about it, but did not understand how I can use the controller from another widget. I created a function in the main widget and pass it to the GlobalKey modal to access it so I can return my variables. But I'm looking for a nicer way to return variables from a modal window. Do you know a way to use controllers from another widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to type text in a ModalBottomSheet and get it in the underlying widget, just use the same TextEditingController in both, initializing and disposing it in your main widget.

Here is a working example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: MyApp(),
    ),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet(
                isScrollControlled: true,
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Material(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: _controller,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }).whenComplete(() => setState(() {})),
            child: Text('Click to enter text'),
          ),
          Text(_controller.text == '' ? 'No text entered yet' : _controller.text),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```